# How to put translation into array in Laravel Form?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to have a prompt box which would be set through the key 'onsubmit' in Form array. This version works:

```
{!! Form::model($currentUser, 
['route' => ['post.users.current.account.index',  $currentUser->id], 
'onsubmit' => 'return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')']) !!}
```

But I am unable to inject a translation into it to make it work. So far I tried this without success:

```
{!! Form::model($currentUser, 
['route' => ['post.users.current.account.index',  $currentUser->id], 
'onsubmit' => 'return confirm(\''.{{trans('Users::users.current.account.index.box.confirm')}}.'\')']) !!}
```

Is there a way to concatenate function output inside the array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

```
{!! Form::model($currentUser, 
['route' => ['post.users.current.account.index',  $currentUser->id], 
'onsubmit' => "return confirm('".trans('Users::users.current.account.index.box.confirm')."')"]) !!}
```